# How can I get the JWT token sent in res.cookie to appear in my browser's cookie storage?

Tags: reactjs, express, cookies, httpcookie, express-jwt

Basically I generated a JWT token and sent it with the res headers from my express server.

code to generate token:
// generate JWT

```
const generateToken = (res, id) => {
    const token = jwt.sign({ id }, process.env.JWT_SECRET, {
        expiresIn: "30d"
    });

    res.cookie("jwt", token, {
        httpOnly: true,
        secure: process.env.NODE_ENV !== "development",
        sameSite: "none",
        maxAge: 30 * 60 * 60 * 24 * 1000
    });
}
```

[Login implementation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7v9Oh.png)

Anytime I make a login request via postman I can see the cookie is present but when I try to do the same in my react app the auth workflow works fine but the cookie doesn't reflect in my browser for some reason.

I am trying to have the cookie being sent with my res headers reflect in my browser's cookie storage. This works just fine when testing with postman but doesnt with my browsers. I've tried everything, clearing the storage, trying other browsers, still the same result.